# sort a SKSpriteNode array according to a specific element

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a SKSpriteNode array declared like this :

```
class rgbNodes: SKSpriteNode
{
}

var colorNode = [rgbNodes]()

colorNode.append(rgbNodes(imageNamed: "Rectangle")) // every time we want to add a new element to this array
```

And I would like to sort every element of this array according to their position.x value, for example, if :

```
colorNode[0].position.x = 25
colorNode[1].position.x = 5
colorNode[2].position.x = 15
```

I want the array to be sorted like this :

```
colorNode[0].position.x = 5
colorNode[1].position.x = 15
colorNode[2].position.x = 25
```

But how can I manage to do it with the sort command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort colorNode, you could do this:

```
colorNode.sort() {
    $0.position.x < $1.position.x
}
```