# Sort array of SKShapeNode elements

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, sprite-kit

Any idea on how to sort an array of `SKShapeNode` elements by their names? Let just assume each `SKShapeNode.name` property is a number 100,23,31,... All of them are group into `shapeNodesCollection`. What should be done to sort it out into another array - `shapeNodesCollectionSorted`? Below you can find some abstract code.

```
class Example: GameScene {

    ...

    var shapeNodesCollection = [SKShapeNode]()
    var shapeNodesCollectionSorted = [SKShapeNode]()

    ...

    shapeNodesCollectionSorted = ... //sorted shapeNodesCollection

}
```

Many thanks to anyone for any contribution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337495/sort-a-skspritenode-array-according-to-a-specific-element

Comment: @Matrin R, much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `name` property is a simple numeric type (e.g., `Int`, `Float`, etc) then this should be enough:

```
var shapeNodesCollectionSorted = shapeNodesCollection.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
```

The `shapeNodesCollectionSorted` will then contain the shapes sorted in *ascending* order according to the `name` property.

Comment: this is it! Thank you.